# javascript before - как копировать содержимое, перед которым добавляем?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из этого:

```
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Второй заголовок</h2>
<h2>Другой заголовок</h2>
```

Сделать это:

```
[tabby title="Заголовок"]<h2>Заголовок</h2>
[tabby title="Второй заголовок"]<h2>Второй заголовок</h2>
[tabby title="Другой заголовок"]<h2>Другой заголовок</h2>
```

То есть, не просто вставляем содержимое перед `<h2>`, но еще и копируем текст, который после h2 (у каждого свой) и размещаем его в `[tabby title="XXXX"]`.
Не силён в этом, а нагуглить не получилось.

Comment: что такое `[tabby title="Заголовок"]`? Это просто текст?

Comment: да, просто текст, в title которого надо копировать то что идёт после h2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.before`](https://api.jquery.com/before/#before-function) может принимать функцию, которая возвращает то, что будет вставлено перед текущим элементом. При этом доступ к самому элементу можно осуществить через `this`.

Получить текст текущего элемента можно с помощью свойства [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Таким образом код может быть следующим

```js
$('h2').before(function() {
  return `[tabby title="${this.textContent}"]`;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Второй заголовок</h2>
<h2>Другой заголовок</h2>
```

Comment: Ты же `this.textContent` из текста превращаешь в html-разметку таким образом?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, побочный эффект ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Qwertiy, с другой стороны, это помешает только если в заголовке будет экранированный html, если будет просто html - то все ок будет